# Inverse of matrix of generalised harmonic numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, matrix-analysis, perturbation-theory

For $s=0,1,\dots$ and $n=1,2,\dots$, denote $r_{n,s}=\sum_{k=1}^n k^s$. It is well-known that $r_{n,s}$ are polynomials in $n$ with leading term $\frac{1}{s+1}n^{s+1}$. Let $R_{n,s}$ be the $(s+1)\times (s+1)$ (symmetric) matrix $$R_{n,s}:=\left( r_{n,i+j-2} \right)_{i=1,\dots,s+1}^{j=1,\dots,s+1}.$$

Let $H_{n,s}$ be the ``leading term'' of $R_{n,s}$, namely
$$ H_{n,s}=\left( \frac{n^{i+j-1}}{i+j-1} \right)_{i,j}$$ and $R_{n,s}=H_{n,s}+O(n^{-1}) H_{n,s}$.

It is an experimental "fact" that $R_{n,s}$ is invertible, with entries rational in $n$, whose "leading term" is given by the matrix
$$ T_{n,s}:=H_{n,s}^{-1}= \left( \frac{q_{i,j}}{n^{i+j-1}} \right)_{i,j} $$
where $q_{i,j}$ are the entries of the corresponding inverse Hilbert matrix, i.e. if $\cal{H}^{(s)}=\left( \frac{1}{i+j-1} \right)_{i,j}$ then $\cal{H}^{-1}=\left(q_{i,j}\right)$.

That is, $R_{n,s}^{-1}=T_{n,s}+O(n^{-1})T_{n,s}$.

I believe these "facts" can be proved using component-wise matrix perturbation theory, and I was wondering if there is some "elementary" proof and/or well-known explicit form for the entries of $R_{n,s}^{-1}$.

Comment: $R = H(1+O(1/n))$ and matrix inversion is continuous (and defined on an open set), which gives your claims. These facts are an immediate consequence of the Neumann series for $(1+A)^{-1}$ for small $A$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: the problem is that one cannot write $R=H(I+O(1/n))$ in this case. Rather, $O(1/n)H$ stands for a matrix whose $i,j$-th entry is $O(1/n)$ times the $i,j$-th entry of $H$.

Comment: It seems to me you're getting this (that is, $R=H(1+B)$ with $\| B\|$ small) anyway here, since $H$, $H^{-1}$ have positive entries, so there are no cancellations when working out the matrix elements of $H^{-1}H$, so an extra $O(n^{-1})$ should keep things small.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Unfortunately, this is not the case. $H^{-1}$ does have negative entries (as does the inverse of the Hilbert matrix), so even for a 2-by-2 case the matrix $H^{-1}R-I$ has $O(1)$ entries.

Comment: In hopes of an explicit form, have you tried Bernoulli's formula for $r_{n,s}$?  I am hoping it leads to a factorization of $R_{n,s}$ in which each factor is easy to invert.